# how do I count the number of words that occur at least once in a string?

Tags: python, string, count

I'm using Python 3.7.  I have an array of unique words ...

```
words = ["abc", "cat", "dog"]
```

Then I have other strings, which may or not contain one or more instances of these words.  How do I figure out the number of occurrences of unique instances of each word in each string?  For example if I have

```
s = "bbb abc abc lll dog"
```

Given the above array, words, the result of counting unique words in "s" should be 2, because "abc" occurs at least once, and "dog" occurs at least once.  Similarly,

```
s2 = "CATTL DOG mmm"
```

would only contain 1 unique word, "dog".  The other words don't occur in the array "words".

Comment: Detecting a string in a list, de-duplicating a list, and counting are all technique st well-documented in tutorials.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way would be:

```
set(words).intersection(s.split(" "))
```

Comment: Oooh I love this, I didn't think of set intersection, only one caveat, depending on the number of times this will be done, you will be creating a set of `words` each time with a performance hit, on the other hand if `words` can be declared as set from the beginning this is what I would go for

Comment: True. The intersection itself is fast. As you say, if the words list is a constant, one conversion (or declaration) is sufficient (zero impact on big O).

Answer (score 0):

A set comprehension is a good choice here

```
words = ['abc', 'cat', 'dog']
s = 'bbb abc abc lll dog'
ss = {w for w in s.split() if w in words}

ss
> {'abc', 'dog'}
```